# Symantec Endpoint Protection fails to install due to error 1603

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, anti-virus, sep

I am trying to install Symantec Endpoint Protection version 12 on Windows 7 64 bit, and during the installation it keeps failing and rolling back. I checked the log file, and the error code I'm getting is 1603.

Comment: What build of SEPP are you installing?

Comment: File Version: 12.0.0.49974

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A co-worker found the solution.
[The installation of Symantec Endpoint Protection (SEP) client fails and rolls back around the point of registering with LiveUpdate](http://service1.symantec.com/support/ent-security.nsf/854fa02b4f5013678825731a007d06af/5c45f3798fdd78e3492575d7001f71c3)

> Solution:
>
> In the registry,
>
> Find
>
> HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User
>   Shell Folders\AppData value=%APPDATA%
>
> and change it to
>
> HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User
>   Shell Folders\AppData
>   value=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming
>
> Install SEP client again.